# Is it possible to delete mysql root user for remote login using mysql_user ansible module?

Tags: mysql, linux, ansible

Is it possible in MySQL to disallow root login remotely using ansible module mysql_user ?

Something like this, but for all host, not onlyansible_fqdn:

```
- name: Delete root MySQL user for remote logins
  mysql_user: 
   user: root
   host: "{{ansible_fqdn}}"
   state: absent
   login_password: abc
   login_user: root
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use the `host_all` option in this.

```
- name: Ensure no user named 'sally' exists at all
  mysql_user:
    name: sally
    host_all: yes
    state: absent
```

Just for the **reference** please follow the **doc**:- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/mysql_user_module.html

Comment: I think, with host_all i also remove root@localhost.

Comment: Yes you can @RobertBielicki, if it does not remove root@localhost then we can use ```host: localhost``` option as well with the above code.